# MySQL - count with join given incorrect result

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
SELECT count(a.users_id) as count
  FROM user_jobs_application a
  join job_shifts s
    on s.id = a.job_shift_id
 where s.jobs_id = 29
   and a.status = 1
 group 
    by a.users_id
```

In this case **count** should be 1, but I am getting 4. I am assuming that this is because of the **join** - when I do this query:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM user_jobs_application a
    join job_shifts s
      on s.id = a.job_shift_id
   where s.jobs_id = 29
     and a.status = 1
```

I am getting 4 rows:

```
<row>
        <field name="users_id">15</field>
        <field name="job_shift_id">246</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="comment"></field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="id">58</field>
        <field name="id">246</field>
        <field name="jobs_id">29</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="shift_date">2020-11-23</field>
        <field name="from">08:00:00</field>
        <field name="to">16:00:00</field>
        <field name="duration">1</field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 05:32:48</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 05:33:44</field>
    </row>

    <row>
        <field name="users_id">15</field>
        <field name="job_shift_id">247</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="comment"></field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="id">59</field>
        <field name="id">247</field>
        <field name="jobs_id">29</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="shift_date">2020-11-24</field>
        <field name="from">08:00:00</field>
        <field name="to">16:00:00</field>
        <field name="duration">1</field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 05:32:48</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 05:33:44</field>
    </row>

    <row>
        <field name="users_id">15</field>
        <field name="job_shift_id">248</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="comment"></field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="id">60</field>
        <field name="id">248</field>
        <field name="jobs_id">29</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="shift_date">2020-11-25</field>
        <field name="from">08:00:00</field>
        <field name="to">16:00:00</field>
        <field name="duration">1</field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 05:32:48</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 05:33:44</field>
    </row>

    <row>
        <field name="users_id">15</field>
        <field name="job_shift_id">249</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="comment"></field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="id">61</field>
        <field name="id">249</field>
        <field name="jobs_id">29</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="shift_date">2020-11-26</field>
        <field name="from">08:00:00</field>
        <field name="to">16:00:00</field>
        <field name="duration">1</field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 05:32:48</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 05:33:44</field>
    </row>
```

but when I do this query, I am getting one row (correct number of rows):

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_jobs_application a
  join job_shifts s
    on s.id = a.job_shift_id
 where s.jobs_id = 29
   and a.status = 1
 group 
   by a.users_id
```

Result:

```
<row>
        <field name="users_id">15</field>
        <field name="job_shift_id">246</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="comment"></field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 06:08:50</field>
        <field name="id">58</field>
        <field name="id">246</field>
        <field name="jobs_id">29</field>
        <field name="status">1</field>
        <field name="shift_date">2020-11-23</field>
        <field name="from">08:00:00</field>
        <field name="to">16:00:00</field>
        <field name="duration">1</field>
        <field name="created_at">2020-11-19 05:32:48</field>
        <field name="updated_at">2020-11-19 05:33:44</field>
    </row>
```

What is the issue here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that adding `ORDER BY` changes the number of rows in the result?

Comment: **ORDER BY** when used without **count** will give correct number of results (in this case one row). But when instead of the **SELECT * ** I use **count(user_jobs_application.users_id) as count** count will be 4, which is incorrect (count needs to be 1)

Comment: If you are saying that your 2nd and 3rd query produce different amounts of rows - provide [mcve].

Comment: ...and/or [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @PM77-1 I made typo here - I meant **GROUP BY**, not  **ORDER BY** - the question still stays the same - how to get the correct count?

Comment: You tell that there is 4 rows before grouping. The output provided shows that all 4 rows have the same `users_id=15`. The query is `SELECT count(a.users_id) ... group by a.users_id` - so the COUNT() **must** be 4, not 1. Where the value `1` is taken from? Maybe you mean that there is 1 unique user_id? Use `SELECT count(DISTINCT a.users_id) ... group by a.users_id`.

Comment: @Akina yes, there is one unique users_id and I need it to be counted that way.

Comment: From the other side - the amount of unique values in the column grouped by this column will always give `1` (or NULL if the value is NULL). So you may use `SELECT 1 AS cnt .. GROUP BY user_id` - the result wil be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT function used with GROUP BY gives you the total count of rows before they are groupped. The result is same, as you use SELECT COUNT(s.id). If you want to know the count uf unique values of the filed, you can use DISTINCT modifier, here as: `SELECT count(DISTINCT a.users_id) as count`

Comment: I do not believe that your first statement is accurate.